# Reverse Geocoding using Mapquest API and Python

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas, mapquest

Hi Everyone so I am trying to Geocode using the Mapquest API. I want to do reverse geocoding by giving the LAT/LONG CSV and process it through a Python Script using Mapquest API. I created the script below but when I get my output from the script I get no response. Can anyone tinker with my script so that I get the JSON out of it and I can parse the address data from the geocoding to another file. Thanks

### Here is my input CSV sample Data

```
objectID    lat lon
1   52.36732733 4.9491406
```

### My Python Script

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests 

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/albertgonzalobautista/Desktop/Testing_MPQ.csv')

# create new columns
df['geocode_data'] = ''
df['address']=''

# function that handles the geocoding requests

def reverseGeocode(latlng):
    result = {}
    url = 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key={1}'
    apikey = 'XXX'
    request = url.format(latlng, apikey)
    data = json.loads(requests.get(request).text)
    if len(data['results']) > 0:
        result = data['results'][0]
    return  result

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df['geocode_data'][i] = reverseGeocode(df['lat'][i].astype(str) + ',' + df['lon'][i].astype(str))

df.to_csv('test8.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

### The output of my script

```
objectID    lat lon geocode_data
1   52.36732733 4.9491406   {'providedLocation': {}, 'locations': []}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not passing the latlng variable into the request url.

Comment: In general, you should do a bit more work to narrow down where the error is occurring in your script.

Comment: Suggest looking at the documentation again: http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/#reverse

Comment: Basically the error in my script is that I am not a getting a returned Address for my location as seen in the output of my script section. With that how do I pass the latlng variable though  the request url?

Comment: What I mean is, your script is doing a lot of different things:
* iterating over a dataframe
* reading single values out of a dataframe
* assigning single values to a dataframe
* making an API call

etc.

If you can narrow down which of those is the problem, you can ask a better question.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I am running a CSV file with multiple Latlongs and I want to run those calls thorugh the Mapquest API so that it will give me a reverse geocoded address. You said earlier that it my latlong is not going through the URL. how do I fix thaT?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following three lines in your function:

```
url = 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key={1}'
apikey = 'XXX'
request = url.format(latlng, apikey)
```

The url that you are sending to the mapquest API does not include the latitude and longitude! You are just sending them your apikey.

If you take a look at their documentation, you can see what format the URL needs to be in:
http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/#reverse

Comment: so I am trying to modify the URL to fit my code. Can you suggest on how I can do it?

Comment: I was hoping to use the JSON too so I can parse the information out if that is possible.

Comment: If you follow the link I posted, it gives an example URL (the section "Reverse Geocode Sample"). What is the difference between that URL and the one in your script?

Comment: How to add the code in folium?

Comment: @AnonymousUser I think that's a different enough topic that you should ask it as a separate question, it would require a lot more context about your situation to answer well.